# Calling a method on every edit of UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm now programming a simple app that has 3 `UITextField`s and if I edit one, the other two should scale together with it.

I tried using

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

this method, but:

- replacement string is the last character that was typed in
- can't figure out how backspace works there
- it is being called a little too early

if I can "fix" the first point(by sending

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [textField text], string];
```

as a parameter), it will not "fix" the second point, because `string` variable is:

```
(lldb) po string
(NSString *) $1 = 0x0080cf14 <object returned empty description>
```

So the question is: is there any method that is being called AFTER `textFieldShouldChangeCharactersInRange:`? Or is there a way to:

- return YES in `textFieldShouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method
- and THEN call a method to change the values of the 2 other `UITextField`s?

**EDIT**

I could use the following:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:textField afterDelay:0.1];
  return YES;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be the safest solution

Comment: Sorry but using afterDelay is a HORRIBLE solution =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backspace works modifying the NSRange with a empty string. What you can do is modify the three text field in the textField:shouldChange and then return NO to the method.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]; // this is what will happen if you return yes to this method

    anotherTextField.text = // do whatever u need
    yetAnotherTextField.text = // do whatever u need
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For textFields:

```
 [yourtextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

 -(void)textFieldDidChange
 {
      //Your Code
 }
```

Comment: The question concerns text fields, not text views!

Comment: That's much better! Careful with the colon though, as the `textFieldDidChange` does not have any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The following code prints correctly the full text of the text view (with the last character that was inserted), can that be useful?

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string length])
        NSLog(@"Current Text:%@", [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string]);
    else
        NSLog(@"Current Text:%@", [textField.text substringWithRange:(NSRange){0, [textField.text length]-1}]);
    return YES;
}
```

The backspace just sends an empty string in the `string` parameter.